# Release Management for Visual Studio 2013 - Release Exception

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, release-management, ms-release-management

Getting the following error after a successful MsBuild on a TFS Build Server:

```
ERROR: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: The attribute 'BuildNumber' is not part of this XElement
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Common.ExtensionMethods.XmlExtensionMethods.GetAttributeValue(XElement element, XName attributeName)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Model.ReleaseComponent.SetBuildToLatest()
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Workflow.Services.ReleaseWorkflowService.InitiateFromBuild(Uri teamFoundationServerUrl, String teamProject, String buildDefinition, String buildNumber, String targetStageName)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Build.Program.Release()
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Build.Program.MainImplementation(String[] args, Action`1 consoleWriter, Action releaseAction)
```

Build is part of Release Management pipeline that automatically deploys to DEV server.

Any ideas?

Comment: What build process template are you using? What version of RM are you using (Update 4, etc)? Are you using an agent-based or vNext release template?

Comment: ReleaseDefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml, RM 2013 Update 4, Agent-based

Comment: Looking through ActivityLog.xml on the BuildServer, the "BuildNumber" doesn't have a corresponding value, which is probably why the exception was generated. But, why would this value not be populated?

<BuildInformationNode Id="028adc1e-7f15-4001-b7bf-efe35e1adca7" ParentId="a2a12c6e-9748-487e-862b-b5663be60b9a" Type="ActivityInput">
  <Fields>
    <InformationField Name="BuildNumber" />
  </Fields>
<Children /></BuildInformationNode>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue:

Had two components in the release process -- Second component in the release process used a different build template than the first. First component deployed successfully, but second component had no builds in TFS yet, so BuildNumber was null.